# FFmpeg transcoding GOP pattern IP

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding, h.264, gop

I need to transcode mpeg2 video via H264 codec and GOP structure should be IP.
I use the following command for this:

> ffmpeg -i INPUT -vcodec libx264 -x264-params
>   keyint=2:scenecut=-1:ref=1 -acodec copy -y out.mpg

Then checked it with ffprobe:

> ffprobe -i out.mpg -show_frames | grep key_frame

And received the following results:

> key_frame=1 
> key_frame=1 
> key_frame=1 
> key_frame=1 
> key_frame=1
>   key_frame=1
>  key_frame=1
>  key_frame=1
>  key_frame=0
>  key_frame=1
>   key_frame=0 
> key_frame=1
>  key_frame=0 
> key_frame=1 
> key_frame=0
>   key_frame=1
>  key_frame=0 
> key_frame=1
>  key_frame=1
>  key_frame=1
>   key_frame=1 
> key_frame=0 
> key_frame=1
>  key_frame=1
>  key_frame=1
>   key_frame=1 
> key_frame=1

Can you please explain how to correct transcoding H264 and set GOP IP Pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -vcodec libx264 -g 2 -acodec copy -y out.mpg
```

---

As per the x264 docs, `scenecut=0` disables scenecut evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried it, but received the same result.

Comment: Works here. Run `ffprobe out.mpg -show_entries frame=key_frame -select_streams v -of compact=p=0`. Audio frames are also reported in your command.

Comment: Much Appreciated!